# Как найти уровень значимости? (в R)

Tags: r, rstudio

В датасете Wine из пакета candisc данные о химическом составе вина, полученного из трех разных культиваров в одном регионе Италии. Сравните гриньолино и барбера по степени щелочности зольных веществ (AlcAsh) при помощи t-теста. Чему равен уровень значимости? Округлите ответ до пятого знака

Столкнулся с ошибкой в своем коде:
`t.test(Cultivar~AlcAsh,data=WineBG)`

Ошибка в t.test.formula(Cultivar ~ AlcAsh, data = WineBG) :
группирующий фактор должен иметь в точности 2 уровня

Никак не могу понять, что нужно сделать, чтобы получить верный ответ.

Comment: функции `t.test()` надо передать два вектора, а не формулу и (неизвестный для функции) параметр `data`. видимо, вы спутали её с функцией `lm()`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1127893/178576